# Animation for Popupwindow

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to replicate the animation which occurs when we open the Overflow menu of Chrome Browser for Android. Here is the video for that animation

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f4i1ad9ky1wjth/video.flv?dl=0

So for animating the loading of items in ListView in this window, i am using the following code in getView() of adapter of this ListView.

```
<set>
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-5%p" android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="700"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

But this effect comes out to be different as compared to the original Chrome Animation? What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual thing happening here with the ListView items are

1. They are translating by  `android:fromYDelta="-1%p" to android:toYDelta="0"`
2. Their alpha value changes `android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"`
3. And the most important thing, the loading of items in the ListView has been delayed using

   `LayoutAnimationController` lac = `new LayoutAnimationController(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this`, `R.anim.animation), 0.3f);`

where 0.3f is the delay.

I was missing the third point.
And here, R.anim.animation is the animation combining points 1 and 2. Here is the complete project. Just the shadow is missing from Pre-Lollipop devices

https://github.com/rahulrj/ChromeOverflowMenu

Answer (score 1):

If you set the "Animator duration scale" to "10x" into developer options, you can see that the items on menu list are being animated in sequence... Not at the same time.

I don't actually tested your code, but I think that this will make all items animate at the same time...

EDIT 1:

You can animate via java code using [setStartDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#setStartDelay(long)) to control the start delay on every view using the position as control variable (**startDelay = position*1000** if you want 1 second between every item).

Comment: Yes, my code loads them at the same time. I want them to be loaded in sequence. How do i do this?

Comment: You hinted towards Animator duration scale. I tried it out by slowing down the animations and it lead me towards LayoutAnimationController which worked for me. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are happening during the animation:

1) The container (which contains the elements, in your case the listview) is being scaled from 0 to 1, it is important that you provide a correct pivot point else the animation wont look like the chrome animation.

2) The elements them self are being animated, they are being faded in. You can do this with just a simple Object animator or a XML animation. I would go with the Object animator because then you have more control. As said by someone else you can add a setStartDelay based on the position but that could cause weird behavior when scrolling in the list.

Things worth noticing:
There are probably library's for ListView Animations I would recommend that you go look at them. You can find a lot of Android library's at https://android-arsenal.com/

Also, when you want to reproduce a certain animation ask yourself: what is exactly happening and how would I find this information. You can slow animations down so it is easier to see what is happening.

Comment: I was looking at the animation and trying out from past 2 days. Then i posted the question. BTW i didnt know about Animator Duration which helped me a lot in finding out the animation. So i tried it out which lead me to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Hey check this out: [ListView Animations](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/04/listview-animation-tutorial.html)

May be this can be useful to you.
I haven't check your code but I am assuming that this can work for you:

```
<set>
<translate android:fromYDelta="-50%p" android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="700"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="700" />
```